# Dual Boot - no choice on boot, only Windows 8 booting

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2

I've installed 12.04 LTS alongside Windows 8, but there is no possibility to choose Ubuntu when it starts. Windows 8 is directly started. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not turned off the secure boot option wihtin Bios. [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) Article gives a good overview on that topic.